error processing @AttributeBinderType annotation '@org.hibernate.annotations.BatchSize
After updating to spring boot 3.2.5 -> 3.3.0, app won't start due to failing of creation of entity manager with error:
error processing @AttributeBinderType annotation '@org.hibernate.annotations.BatchSize


Turns out that @BatchSize is no longer allowed on non-collection attributes.
Till now it was allowed, but had no effect and was ignored by Hibernate.
So to solve this problem, you have to remove @BatchSize from ToOne mappings
